# Drag and Drop Function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have two boxes and both can be used for drag and drop events. I have to highlight only one box at a time where drop function needs to be happen

Comment: Look at [HTML5's drag and drop](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp) and capturing [the events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DragDrop/Drag_and_Drop) with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Detect when a drag event occurs on the `document`. Like:

```
$(document).on("dragstart", ..);
```

Then add a class to the *box* that you want to highlight:

```
$("#drop_box").addClass("highlight");
```

Then also remeber to remove the class again on `"dragend"`

Comment: `add_class` is pretty new to me in jQuery - did you mean `addClass()` http://api.jquery.com/addClass/ ;-)